# Translating "as many times as" to an equation

Tags: word-problem

I have this problem:

> Carla has 3 times as many cars, c, as she has trucks, t, how many cars does she have?

Is it correct to assume I can translate it to this:

$$c = 3t$$

Also, by that same logic I translated this:

> Carlas has 1/4 times as many cars as she has trucks, how many cars does she have?

$$c = (1/4)t$$

Comment: An easy way to check if you've interpreted it correctly is to put a few numbers in and see if it makes sense. What you have there looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question, but your analysis is correct

Comment: @Leucippus: actually, the question in the middle asks if the interpretation shown is correct.  This answers that question.  However, this answer could definitely be filled in with more details and supporting logic...

Comment: I agree with @abiessu that the only point raised by the Question (in the title and in the middle of the body) is whether the "translating... to an equation" is done correctly.  So this is one of those rare cases where a one-line response is adequate.

Comment: There is not really any way to answer this question more in depth, the question is a very simple one. You might suggest that I had commented instead, but I think it is better to answer than to comment, as it shows that the question has been answered to people looking. If I should just comment instead next time then please explain why you think that is better